# How to break the inheritance to modify the permissions of current page in sharepoint using Javascript(JSOM)?

Tags: javascript, permissions, jsom

I want to break the inheritance to modify the permissions of current page in SharePoint using JavaScript(JSOM)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below SharePoint JSOM code snippet to break the current page  or list item permission and assign the new permission to the group.

```
    function breakpermission(groupName) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(_spPageContextInfo.listTitle);
    oListItem = oList.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);
    oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(false);

    //Bind Contribute permission to the Group
    oGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups().getByName(groupName);
    var groupPermissionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
    groupPermissionBinding.add(clientContext.get_web().get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.contributor));

    //Assign binded permission to the page or listitem
    oListItem.get_roleAssignments().add(oGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);

    clientContext.load(oGroup);
    clientContext.load(oList);
    clientContext.load(oListItem);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
            alert('Applied the unique permission and assigns contribute permission to the group');
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }));
}
function injectMethod() {
    breakpermission("Site Members");
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(injectMethod, "sp.js");
```

I'll hope, the above code helps you.